# mysql_num_rows and condition

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysql-num-rows

Hi guys I am trying to use something more efficient instead of using `mysql_num_rows` from multiple queries. Am I able to use one query and for example count `mysql_num_rows()` based on condition if `$type=="a"`? And declare variable for each.. for b rows, c rows, d rows etc. Thank you

```
$rows_a = mysql_query("SELECT $type FROM table WHERE $type = 'a'");
$a_rows = mysql_num_rows($rows_a);

$rows_b = mysql_query("SELECT $type FROM table WHERE $type = 'b'");
$b_rows = mysql_num_rows($rows_b);

$rows_c = mysql_query("SELECT $type FROM table WHERE $type = 'c'");
$c_rows = mysql_num_rows($rows_c);

$rows_d = mysql_query("SELECT $type FROM table WHERE $type = 'd'");
$d_rows = mysql_num_rows($rows_d);
```

Comment: How about something like `SELECT count(type), type FROM table GROUP BY type`?

Comment: I will give the obligatory "don't use `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated" warning. Don't use them. they are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), type FROM table GROUP BY type
```

Comment: And as a bonus, no SQL injection is possible. :)

Comment: What was the point of the edit? I see absolutely no difference in the result.

Comment: The edit: You did backticks. It was replaced with a codeblock

Comment: Yes, but WHY? It made no difference in the end output. I keep seeing people do this, and I don't get why. I like the backticks, it's easier to hit ` twice than space 4 times.

Comment: It only matters on code that spans multiple lines. It puts it in a full width div and does preformatted whitespace. backticks only get you monospace font I think

Comment: Right - and my point is this was a one liner. People keep changing my single lines to be code blocks for SQL, when the only thing that changes is it's a full-width div? I am only asking because it keeps happening and it seems weird.

Comment: Ok, well most people think that sql statements are not inline code. backticks are for inline code. It is just the convention here.

Answer (score 0):

Could be like this : ( if no primary ID column)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows, type FROM table WHERE type IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') GROUP BY type
```

or dynamic :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows, type FROM table WHERE type IN ('select types from a sub query') GROUP BY type
```

Comment: This isn't bad. It answers the poster's question exactly. But it is less maintainable than the other solution in my opinion, because it requires explicitly listing types. What if they change?

Comment: I liked your original answer better. This makes the `WHERE` clause pointless.

Comment: Yeah, for this one it is. 
I think when the types are coming from any other sub-query then it will be ok.

Comment: Ok, then I would mention that in your post. Give both options. let the reader decide.